# Speeding up dir() query

Tags: r

I'm listing files in a directory using the command:

```
dir(path = "path.to.dir", full.names = TRUE, recursive = TRUE, include.dirs = TRUE)
```

In this directory there are about 50.000 files and six subfolders each with around the same amount of files. The directory is on a network storage (and cannot be moved, since its size is several hundreds of GBs). It's all tar.gz files, if that matters, but I'm interested in the names only.

This query takes very long. I'd say around 20 min. If I open the windows explorer and navigate to the folder, it only takes seconds until I see the files. In addition, if I monitor the network usage, it's only around 0.5 to 1 % (the connection 1GBit/s).

Is there a way to speed up this query?

Comment: On Unix you can use the system utility `find`, e.g. `system('find /path/to/dir', intern = TRUE)`, see if it's any faster.

Comment: Unfortunatly I'm limited on windows.

Comment: I realized that using `dir /s /b` on a windows machine is much faster.